# when using Python's open() function to read a binary file, only part of the file is read

Tags: python, file, jpeg, binaryfiles

I am trying to read data from a jpg file using the `open()` function in python. For some reason, some of the file data is being lost. Here is what I tried:

```py
file = open(imageDir, 'r')
data = file.read()
print data
```

When I try to re-write the data into a new file, the new file is corrupt.

Comment: How do you know that? Also, what is the meaning of "lines" in a jpg file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'rb'` for binary file. Also, I suggest you not use `dir` for what is actually a filename; and use the context syntax for the read operation.

```
with file = open(filename, 'rb')
     data = file.read()
```

Comment: `dir` is a built-in global function, one more reason why it's a bad variable name

Answer (score 1):

You should open file in binary mode like this

```
file = open(dir, 'rb')
```

By default it’s opened in text mode